# JS Promises in code-golf?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, output

Should [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) submissions written in JS that return a promise be allowed?

For example:

```js
Promise.resolve("hi")
```

Doesn't output `"hi"`, but outputs a promise that resolves with the value of `"hi"`. If you want "hi", then

```js
Promise.resolve("hi").then(console.log)
```

is needed. Should the `.then(console.log)` part be required (and therefore part of the byte count)?

Comment: You might want to clarify what a promise is.

Answer (score 6):

## No byte penalty

This is just an (abnormal) way of output that can show up often in `fetch` / [networking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) submissions. I think this is absolutely fine.

Comment: In the future, please don't post answers for both sides. Let the people who actually support a side post an answer for it. Also, you don't need to make the answers community wiki. (you can, it's just not needed)